# How do I keep the child nodes in the same line in XML in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML in the following format:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="...css" type="text/css"?>
<repub>
    <head>
        <title>Main Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <sec name="sec_1">
        <title>Section Title</title>
        <break name="article_6-3">
            <h1>
                <page num="6" />
                <b>Article Title</b>
            </h1>
            <fig><img src="images/img_6-3.jpg" alt=""/></fig>
            <p>
                <b>
                <i>Paragraph italic value</i> and bold value.</b>
            </p>
            <pw>Paragraph value</pw>
        <fig><img src="images/img_6-4.jpg" alt=""/></fig>
</break>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

I want the XML child nodes to be in the same line as the parent, like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="...css" type="text/css"?>
<repub>
    <head>
        <title>Main Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <sec name="sec_1">
        <title>Section Title</title>
        <break name="article_6-3">
            <h1><page num="6" /><b>Article Title</b></h1> //Change 1
            <fig><img src="images/img_6-3.jpg" alt=""/></fig>
            <p><b><i>Paragraph italic value</i> and bold value.</b></p> //Change 2
            <pw>Paragraph value</pw>
        <fig><img src="images/img_6-4.jpg" alt=""/></fig>
</break>
</sec>
</body>
</repub>
```

Upon creating the XML, every time the indent also comes up and I can try to somehow manage to remove the indentation, but I am totally clueless as to how can I keep the child nodes in the same line as the parent.

I don't know what to do. Please help.

Regards
Aman

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what text editor you're using. I'll assume you're working with Visual Studio, in which the code auto reformats each time you either paste a code or retype the `>` in the end tag (e.g `</head>`).

To turn it off, just go to:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > XML > Formatting

And uncheck "On paste from clipboard" and "On completion of end tag" (under Auto Reformat)